# Cut from negative integer to last item in list in Hy

Tags: hy

If `(list (range 10))` is `[0 ... 9]`, and `(cut (list (range 10)) -5 -1)` is `[5, 6, 7, 8]`, then how do I include the last item in the list as well, i.e. `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`? I've tried `(cut (list (range 10)) -5 0)` and `(cut (list (range 10)) -5 1)`, but both give me empty lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `None` as the stop argument, as in `(cut (list (range 10)) -5 None)`. The difference between `(cut x -5)` and `(cut x -5 None)` is the same as between `x[slice(-5)]` and `x[slice(-5, None)]` in Python, or equivalently `x[:-5]` and `x[-5:]`.

Comment: Yep; that was it. Thanks for the help! Although, quick related question, if I may: how would I do something like `list(range(10))[::-1]`, i.e. reversing the list? I assume it's not possible with cut, but I don't understand how to use the slice function.

Comment: @ShadowRylander The Python syntax `::-1` is shorthand for `None : None : -1`, so use `None` in `cut`.

Comment: Ah, right; `(cut (list (range 0 10)) None None -1)` did the trick! Thank you kindly for all the help!